# Lock layers on layers panel

Tags: qgis

Is there any way to lock layers in QGIS to prevent them from being accidentally deleted like you can in Illustrator or CAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Project / Properties / Data sources** and then you can fine-tune **per layer** the rules you want to "protect" your project.

Comment: Perfect thankyou. I have to say it would be easier if a padlock symbol was applied next to the “eye” icon on each layer. Also calling it “required” isn’t what would call logical.