# Wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, vector-layer, runtimeerror

The main goal is to remove this error:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted.
```

It appears when a user (I'm in the testing phase) deletes a QGIS layer from the layer list and leaves a plug-in enabled that still stores data from the layers even though it has been deleted.

```
ptpla = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OT_PTPL_A') # the layer is listed in the QGIS Program 
if ptpla:
        ptpl = ptpla[0]
        unique_idensimc = set()
        unique_idenulic = set()
        if ptpl and ptpl.isValid() and self.modelSimcPtpl.rowCount() < 1: #here appers the problem
        # Get attributes from the layer and add them to the model. It only loads once at the beginning
            for feature in ptpl.getFeatures():
                idenulic = str(feature.attributes()[ptpl.fields().indexFromName('FEATUREID')])
                 #...
            self.dlg.pushButton_47.clicked.connect(self.markPtpl) # this line was initially outside the If, ​​but it did not solve the problem
```

The error appears with the ptpla variable - if the layer it downloaded has been deleted, the variable becomes empty.

I tried with else conditions (example in the previous post), but do has no effect.

This error also appears in the "markPtpl" function (2nd independent place)
The function is triggered with a button (pushButton) that retrieves data from the comboBox entered above. More details below

'''
ptpl = ptpla[0]
simcPtpl = self.dlg.comboBox_29.currentText()
ulicPtpl = self.dlg.comboBox_30.currentText()
expression= f'IDENTYFIKATORSIMC= {simcPtpl} AND IDENTYFIKATORULIC = {ulicPtpl}' #after removing the layer from QGIS's layer list, comboBoxes still store data, but do not download to the query

```
ptpl.selectByExpression(expression) #error after removing a layer from the QGIS's layer list crashes here, but adding else for this condition here does not solve the problem
dataPtpl = []
if self.model8.rowCount() > 0: #...
```

I'd tried with else statements and pass, but both doesn't solve it.

Have your different idea to solve it?

Comment: As it is currently written, your question will attract opinion-based answers [which are discouraged on this site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Have you thought about how you want to handle the situation. For example, do you want to prevent the user removing the layer? (In which case you might consider [protecting it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364024/lock-layers-on-layers-panel)). Or, would you prefer the plugin to recognise when the layer is removed and not attempt the code in your question?

Comment: I prefer second option. About first I need to ask my boss